# Spam post should not be upvoted!

Tags: discussion, spam

I have seen an user which reputation is "6" and I saw one user up-voted the spam post.

Spam post should not be up-voted!

Comment: Yes, but even if they are upvoted the outcome does not change, are end up deleted, right?

Comment: Don't downvote spam.  Just use the spam flag, and not another one.  It may seem counterintuitive, but downvoting can make spam stay around longer in the system.  The spam flag is also special.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Suppose I use both down vote and spam flag for a spam question. Is not it make fast to delete that questions? Compare to using only spam flag.

Comment: @mchar it is a bad idea to up-vote spam, since the permissions users have depends on their reputation. Would you want to make spammers reach a reputation of 50, so they can spam on meta, have new users restrictions removed, up-vote for spam posts, flag posts just to fill the flag queue, spam in chat, and comment everywhere?

Comment: I think that spammers are being deleted along with their posts, if I'm not mistaken and **No** I wouldn't want spammers to overwhelm DA :)

Comment: @Smalution If you downvote the post and flag it as spam, it may actually take longer for it to go away.  When the vote count hits a certain point, it will disappear from the home page, and catch fewer flags, which means it will take longer to get autodeleted and may stay around until a moderator can handle the flag.

Comment: Thanks @mpdonadio for the clarification.

Comment: You can blame [Tim Post's cat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/295232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up-voting and down-voting spam are both bad actions that just make spam stay around longer. Down-voting and flagging as spam doesn't make the spam go away faster.

Just flag the spam as spam; when the user account accumulates enough spam flags, the user will be blocked from posting further spam, and the account will be identified as spammer network-wide. This means any associated account used on other Stack Exchange sites will not be able to spam too.